# How to convert or write this Javascript array in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, json, list, arraylist

I want to create this array in C# and send it via Json to javascript.
How I could write this in C#?

This is array in Javascript;

```
var aa =  [{
                name: 'D1',
                data: [
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 12, 12, 10, 10), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 13, 18, 01, 04), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 14, 14, 11, 44), 0],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 15, 14, 11, 44), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 16, 14, 18, 44), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 17, 15, 11, 44), 0],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 18, 16, 15, 44), 1]
             ]
            }, {
                name: 'D2',
                data: [
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 12), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 13), 0],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 14), 0],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 15), 0],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 16), 1],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 16), 0],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 17), 0],
                [Date.UTC(2010, 0, 18), 0]
             ]
            }];
```

I tried to create the same array in c#:

```
public class chData
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int value { get; set; }
    }

    public class finallist
    {
        public string name { get; set;} 
        public List<chData> data { get; set;} 
    }

   List<chData> D1data= new List<chData>
         { 
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,01) , value = 2},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,05), value = 1},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,10), value = 1},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,15), value = 0},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,20), value = 1},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,25), value = 3},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,30), value = 2},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,35), value = 1},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,40), value = 1},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,45), value = 3},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,50), value = 1},
             new chData {Date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,01,15), value = 2}

          };

 List<finallist> Finaldata= new List<finallist>();
 Finaldata.Add(new finallist { name = "D1", data = D1data});
 return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Finaldata);
```

I have some issue with the structured of the array in C#, it doesn't work!
I am sure I did something wrong in C# code.

this is my javascript code

```
var aa =[];    
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Default.aspx/getData",
                    data: "{}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                       aa = eval((data.d).replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
                       },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('#Err');
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: How is your resulting JSON array incorrect? Can you add in what your code generated?

Comment: Given that you use `Date.UTC` in the Javascript you might want to use the `DateTime` constructor that takes a `DateTimeKind` and specify that you want it as UTC.

Comment: yes Json array is incorrect and I think the problem is in the structure of the c# array! I am trying to build chart this is my javascript code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the JSON structure you intend to, you need to change your code so that each element of the `data` property is an object array:

```
public class finallist {
  public string name { get; set; }
  public List<object[]> data { get; set; }
}

var D1data = new List<object[]>
{ 
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,05),  1},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,10),  1},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,15),  0},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,20),  1},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,25),  3},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,30),  2},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,35),  1},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,40),  1},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,45),  3},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,00,50),  1},
     new object[] { new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 00,01,15),  2}

};

List<finallist> Finaldata = new List<finallist>();
Finaldata.Add(new finallist { name = "D1", data = D1data });
return  JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Finaldata, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: one issue I have! the date format is 2014-01-11T00:00:00 I need it to be as this format 1263297600000!! any idea how I can converted it!

Comment: you can try this: `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Finaldata, new JsonConverter[] {new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.JavaScriptDateTimeConverter()});`

Answer (score 2):

finallist.data should be an array of arrays:

```
var convertable = Finaldata.Select(f => new
{
    f.name,
    data = f.data.Select(d => new object[] { d.Date, d.value })
});

return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(convertable);
```

result will be equivalent to your json:

```
[{"name":"D1","data":[
    ["2014-01-01T00:00:01",2],
    ["2014-01-01T00:00:05",1], ...
```